# isomorphism between multiplicative groups of quotient rings $GF(2)[x]/p(x)$

Tags: finite-fields, group-isomorphism

I am interested in an isomorphism between two multiplicative groups of quotient rings $GF(2)[x]/p(x)$, specifically an algorithmic method of determining a mapping between elements.

One is the group $G_1$ of all elements $x^{jk} \bmod p_1(x)$ where $p_1(x)$ is a primitive polynomial of degree $n$, and $j$ is an integer such that $1 < j < m = 2^n-1$ and $j | m$.

The other is a group $G_2$ of all elements $x^k \bmod p_2(x)$ where $p_2(x)$ is a non-primitive polynomial of degree $n$, and the order of the group $G_2$ is $(2^n-1)/j$.

For example, consider $p_1(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$ and $j=15$, where group $G_1$ has elements $1$, $x^{15} = x^5 + x^2 + x$, $x^{30} = x^6 + x^5$, etc., and $p_2(x) = x^8 + x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$, where group $G_2$ has elements $1$, $x$, $x^2$, $x^3$, $x^4$, $x^5$, $x^6$, $x^7$, $x^7 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1$, etc.

Both groups are cyclic with order 17, but I don't know how I could algorithmically calculate a mapping between elements, aside from just taking $x^{jk}$ in group $G_1$ and $x^k$ in group $G_2$ and just creating a table of the two for each value of $k$.

Any suggestions on determining a mapping function for each direction?

Comment: Is this for some computer program? In that case there's nothing wrong with having a look-up table. What is best probably depends on how you have implemented the rest of it. Describing an isomorphism is trivial in the sense that if $\alpha$ is the coset $x+\langle p_1(x)\rangle$ and $\beta$ is the coset $x+\langle p_2(x)\rangle$, then the mapping $\beta^k\mapsto \alpha^{15k}$ works. This subgroup is the kernel of the relative norm map $N:GF(256)^*\to GF(16)^*, N(z)=z^{17}$. There are other ways of listing the elements of the kernel, but don't know if they help your cause.

Comment: Yeah, it's for a computer program, but the example above is just a small example, and the ones I'm interested have much larger values of $n$ so a lookup table is impractical.

Comment: Also how do you go the other direction? Finding the 15th root seems impossible in a field where 15 divides the order of the field.

Comment: I don't know :-( May be another internal representation of the field will help, may be not? If it is always the case that $n=2t$ and $j=2^t+1$, then there is a different way of writing the elements of the subgroup $G$ of order $j$, namely
$$G=\{1\}\cup\{\frac{\gamma+z}{\overline{\gamma}+z}\mid z\in GF(2^t)\},$$ where $\gamma$ is a generator of $G$. Taking advantage may necessitate massive restructuring. And I don't know if this is at all well suited for other things you need to do :-(
$